# How do you nest all component scss in a selector in vue?

Tags: vue.js, sass, vue-component

For example, if my app has two components with this SCSS

A component:

```
  <style lang="scss" scoped>
    .example {
      color: red;
    }
   </style>
```

Another component:

```
  <style lang="scss" scoped>
    .another-example{
      background: yellow;
    }
   </style>
```

Then I would like to have the SCSS from each component nested into one selector, so the resulting CSS will be

```
#my-app .example {
  color: red;
}
#my-app .another-example{
  background: yellow;
}
```

Is it possible to do this without going into every single component and nesting the SCSS inside the #my-app selector in every component?

Comment: Shouldn't matter; the `scoped` parameter already scopes the CSS rules to the current component, which is presumably part of `my-app`.

Comment: @ceejayoz It matters because I have other CSS that could for example be #my-app .h1 which is considered more specific than the scoped CSS for the component and overrides it.

Comment: Sounds a bit like the general structure of your CSS is a little weird and you try to hack your way out of it now. This shouldn't be an issue really. If you have top-level CSS overwriting your component level CSS, you could always just `!important` the component level class props. But this could make it weird to maintain down the line because some things get overwritten, others maybe won't. Could you maybe show a real example of why you would need to set up your CSS in this way?

Comment: @rie There are parts of the site authored by someone else which use CSS loaded from an outside source that could change at any time and we have no control over it. That is not my decision and I can't change it. That CSS is colliding with our CSS and so I am wrapping all of our CSS in #my-app to encapsulate it.

Comment: Ah I see. This seems to be the way to go then to surely avoid collisions which are out of your control. I cannot think of anything else at the top of my head that would help you avoid collisions